# write a raster layer in grass from R with writeRAST

Tags: raster, rgrass7

I have a raster in R like

```
> str(my.raster)
Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ name        : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
  .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
  .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
  .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ nbands      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
  .. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
  .. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 0
  .. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 0
  .. .. ..@ driver      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
  ..@ data    :Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ values    : num [1:80936] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  .. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
  .. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
  .. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ attributes: list()
  .. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ min       : num 0.338
  .. .. ..@ max       : num 0.948
  .. .. ..@ band      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ names     : chr ""
  ..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
  ..@ title   : chr(0) 
  ..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
  .. .. ..@ xmin: num -15.6
  .. .. ..@ xmax: num -15
  .. .. ..@ ymin: num 15.7
  .. .. ..@ ymax: num 16.3
  ..@ rotated : logi FALSE
  ..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
  .. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
  ..@ ncols   : int 268
  ..@ nrows   : int 302
  ..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  ..@ history : list()
  ..@ z       : list()
```

I want to write it in GRASS7 data base. I have, of course, loads `rgrass7` and I tried.

```
> writeRAST(my.raster, "oct_dec")
```

but

```
Error in x@data[[zcol]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

I don't understand how to deal with this error in raster context.

Edit ----------------------------------------------------------------------

A reproductible exemple

```
library(raster)
library(rgrass7)
# initialisation GRASS
initGRASS(gisBase = "/usr/lib/grass72", home = tempdir(),
          gisDbase = "/home/user/Documents/grassDB/",
          location = "Modis_ndvi", mapset = "PERMANENT")
r1 <- raster(ncol = 5, nrow = 10, xmn = 0, xmx = 5, ymn = 0, ymx = 10)
values(r1) <- 1:50  # Note 50 is the total number of cells in the grid. 
r1
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 10, 5, 50  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
# extent      : 0, 5, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : in memory
# names       : layer 
# values      : 1, 50  (min, max)
proj4string(r1) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 

writeRAST(r1, "test_r1")
# Error in x@data[[zcol]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

I'm using grass72, GDAL 2.1.3 and`sessionInfo()` give me

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rgrass7_0.1-9       XML_3.98-1.6        rasterVis_0.41      latticeExtra_0.6-28 RColorBrewer_1.1-2  lattice_0.20-35     magrittr_1.5       
 [8] rgdal_1.2-7         doParallel_1.0.10   iterators_1.0.8     foreach_1.4.3       raster_2.5-8        sp_1.2-4           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.10      codetools_0.2-15  zoo_1.8-0         viridisLite_0.2.0 grid_3.4.0        hexbin_1.27.1     tools_3.4.0       compiler_3.4.0
```

This error seems to be knowed on old sp package version ...

Comment: Would be easier to help if you provide a reproductible example with R utils::sessionInfo() and GRASS 7 version, it can interesting to know also if you are using the gdal-grass pluging

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help of `rgrass7::writeRAST`

```
 writeRAST(x, vname, zcol = 1, NODATA=NULL,
  ignore.stderr = get.ignore.stderrOption(), useGDAL=get.useGDALOption(),
  overwrite=FALSE, flags=NULL, drivername="GTiff")

....

   x: A SpatialGridDataFrame object for export to GRASS as a raster
      layer
```

You need to coerce your `Raster` object to `SpatialGridDataFrame` and then upload. This should hopefully work

```
writeRAST(as(r1, "SpatialGridDataFrame"), "test_r1")
```

May be a this point we can write a small wrapper to save few keystrokes.

Hope it helps